# Aggregation and Percentage in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

My 1st SSRS Report Looks like as in Table 1.

The output of the report is controlled by 2 parameters: Class and Section, and the user can enter these to view the report.

I am trying to generate the 2nd report (table 2) which gives a summary of the 1st report.

Any idea how I can accomplish the 2nd report?

[image]

Comment: @NickyvV: Thanks i will take care hence forward........ :)

Comment: I am not sure whether it is achievable through SSRS. Please help

Comment: I believe this is a pretty basic count with row groups example with filters on the parameters selected. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @NickyvV: i did a page breaker after last column of 1st table than
used the Matrix table and in data section used grade

but i am not able to achieve it. Please help

Comment: You should put the `SUBJECT_CODE` and `SUBJECT_NAME` in row groups and count the number of A grades, e.g. `SUM(IIF(Grade="A", 1, 0))`. The GrandTotal row can be added to the matrix itself by adding a total

Comment: @NickyvV: Thanks  a lot....... its working for me.